# In Visual Studio, how do I set a keyboard shortcut for "ReSharper -> Unit Tests -> Run Unit Tests"?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2019, resharper

I am using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7.6 and ReSharper 2020.2.1.

Does anyone know how to set a keyboard shortcut for **ReSharper -> Unit Tests -> Run Unit Tests**? For me it used to be **Ctrl+U,R**, but I lost it in a recent ReSharper update.

[image: Screenshot of the ReSharper menu]

When I go to **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard**, I get this list. I find it very difficult to locate anything in this list. I have searched but I cannot guess the name of the command I need.

Is there a convenient way to find out?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after searching the [ReSharper community forum](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=shortcut%20unit%20tests).

It's **ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTestRunFromContext**.

[image]